# How to redirect to child route on useRoutes mode?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I want to redirect to `"/building"` when I load the root path `"/"`.
I use v6 of `react-router-dom`.

This is my config.

```
const routes: Array<Route> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: () => import('@/layout/layout'),
    children: [
      {
        path: 'building',
        element: () => import('@/pages/buildingPortfolio'),
      },
      {
        path: 'account',
        element: () => import('@/pages/manageAccount'),

        children: [
          {
            path: 'users',
            element: () => import('@/pages/manageAccount/users'),
          },
          {
            path: 'api-keys',
            element: () => import('@/pages/manageAccount/apiKeys'),
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
];

function LazyElement({ routeElement }: RouteElement) {
  const LazyComponent = lazy(routeElement);
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
      <LazyComponent />
    </Suspense>
  );
}

function wrapRoutesWithLazy(routes: Route[]) {
  routes.forEach((route) => {
    const routeElement = route.element;
    route.element = (<LazyElement routeElement={routeElement} />) as any;
    if (route.children) {
      wrapRoutesWithLazy(route.children);
    }
  });
}

wrapRoutesWithLazy(routes);

export default routes;
```

I try to replace this

```
path: '/',
element: () => import('@/layout/layout'),
```

to

```
path: '/',
element: <Navigate to="/building" />,
```

And when return type of `element` is not `Promise`, then I skip to wrapper it use `React.lazy`

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I solved it.
The key point is add this part in children.

```
      {
        path: '',
        skipLazyLoad: true,
        element: <Navigate to="building" />,
```

And this is the whole file.

```
import { lazy, ReactElement, Suspense } from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

interface Route {
  path?: string;
  element: (() => Promise<any>) | ReactElement;
  end?: boolean;
  children?: Route[];
  skipLazyLoad?: boolean;
}
interface RouteElement {
  routeElement: () => Promise<any>;
}

const routes: Array<Route> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: () => import('@/layout/layout'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        skipLazyLoad: true,
        element: <Navigate to="building" />,
      },
      {
        path: 'building',
        element: () => import('@/pages/buildingPortfolio'),
      },
      {
        path: 'account',
        element: () => import('@/pages/manageAccount'),
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            skipLazyLoad: true,
            element: <Navigate to="users" />,
          },
          {
            path: 'users',
            element: () => import('@/pages/manageAccount/users'),
          },
          {
            path: 'api-keys',
            element: () => import('@/pages/manageAccount/apiKeys'),
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    element: () => import('@/pages/notFound'),
  },
];

function LazyElement({ routeElement }: RouteElement) {
  const LazyComponent = lazy(routeElement);
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
      <LazyComponent />
    </Suspense>
  );
}

function wrapRoutesWithLazy(routes: Route[]) {
  routes.forEach((route) => {
    if (route.skipLazyLoad) return;

    const routeElement = route.element as () => Promise<any>;
    route.element = (<LazyElement routeElement={routeElement} />) as any;
    if (route.children) {
      wrapRoutesWithLazy(route.children);
    }
  });
}

wrapRoutesWithLazy(routes);

export default routes;
```